# MinGW компилирует ошибочный исходник

Tags: mingw, codeblocks, c99

Здравствуйте, мне очень нужна помощь.

Работаю в Code::Blocks, пишу на C.
Недавно наткнулся на очень неприятную проблему. Суть ее в следующем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким-то образом Cоde::Blocks умудряется компилировать ошибочный код, даже не выводя никаких предупреждений. Флаги предупреждения выставлены таким образом, чтобы C::B показывал все предупреждения. И он показывает, отслеживает очень многое и очень запутанное, но не элементарщину.

Самое неприятное даже не в том, что C::B позволяет создать структуру с членом-указателем на неизвестную структуру. Самая соль в том, что при несоответствии прототипа функции код успешно генерируется и запускается.

Только, ясное дело, такой код будет вести себя непредсказуемо.

Подскажите, что с этим делать?

Я пробовал найти адекватную замену C::B и MinGW - не нашел. Visual Studio очень удобная, но в своем составе (даже 2017 версия) содержит бородатый С-компилятор, который не в состоянии собрать корректный C89 код.

Я пробовал компилировать приведенный пример в других средах и другими компиляторами - там никаких проблем нет: в худшем случае выводится предупреждение о несоответствии, в лучшем - ошибка.

Если это нельзя решить в C::B, порекомендуйте IDE и компилятор C90++ для Windows.

Comment: пожалуйста, прекратите называть C::B компилятором. Он не умеет компилировать код. Он пользуется gcc. Указанный код достаточно правильный с точки зрения с компилятора.

Comment: Я не называл C::B компилятором, я сказал, что C::B компилирует (естественно, при помощи MinGW) код, который не должен компилироваться.

Comment: Тогда пишите, что код компилируется в C::B, а не с помощью C::B. Код абсолютно нормальный с точки зрения с компилятора. Более того, его и clang компилирует. Но может Вам поможет [pelles c](http://www.pellesc.de/index.php%3Fpage%3Ddownload).

Comment: Вы можете объяснить, почему код, в котором прототип функции не соответствует ее определению, а так же имеется структура с указателем на непонятно что, почему такой код рабочий?

Comment: в структуре указатель. Указатель это 4 (или 8 байт). Так что, пока не попытаться разыменовать, ничего страшного и не произойдет. Более того, эта структура даже не используется (а лексически она корректна). В случае параметров - количество параметров совпадает и их размеры - все хорошо. Да, синхронизировать прототимы нужно самому.

Comment: но если написать void func(const int *i); компилятор будет ругаться)

Comment: pelles c компилятор попробовали? как он? и на будущее - никогда, никогда не постите код скриншотом, пожалейте других.

Comment: Чем плох скриншот с примером, очищенным от всего лишнего?

Comment: этот код сложно скопировать - это раз, второе - ошибка может быть только в самом коде найдена (например, вместо латинской o, написана кириллическая о.

Comment: Понял. То есть, код и в самом деле является корректным? К сожалению, не обладаю достаточными знаниями английского, чтобы вдоль и поперек изучить Стандарт. Я пробовал Pelles C, он пригоден лишь для небольших проектов, в больших он выдает кучу #error без расшифровок.

Comment: все зависит от того, что считать корректным. С точки зрения программиста код плохой, но компилятор переварит.  Pelles C имеет неплохой компилятор, возможно просто Ваш код нужно доделывать и исправлять.

Comment: Я заинтересовался этим вопросом потому, что веду разработку крупного проекта, в котором несколько десятков тысяч строк. Кода много, поэтому проверять каждое объявление/определение очень тяжело, так или иначе где-то имеется несоответствие из-за невнимательности. И компилятор коварно молчит, продолжая компилировать код, который вроде бы и работает, но без гарантий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наличие/отсутствие `const` в указанном месте не несёт какого-либо сайд-эффекта на работу кода за пределами функции.

Внутри функции вы имеете дело с копией указателя на изначальную переменную `i` и можете, при желании, изменять его (использовать как указатель на другой `int`). Но это изменение наружу не выйдет.

Например, если вы перепишите код вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(int * const);

int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    int * const j = &i;
    func(j);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void func(int *a)
{
    int tmp = 4;
    a = &tmp;
    printf("%d\n", *a);
}
```

Всё по прежнему будет компилироваться без варнингов и `j` в `main` так и останется указателем на `i`.

Comment: Я понимаю. Этот код я привел, как упрощенный пример, чтобы было понятно, в чем заключается проблема при компиляции. В рабочем коде довольно часто встречаются параметры функции вида: (int *const *a) или (i **const a). В общем, я так понял, компилятор С не обязан по стандарту контролировать соответствие таких вот сложных параметров в прототипах и объявлениях функций? Например, const int *i и int *i компилятор определяет, как разные и сообщает об ошибке. Но int *const i и int *i для него приемлемое несоответствие...

Comment: @Максим `const int *i` - указатель на константу, а `int *i` - указатель на переменную. Естественно, это разные вещи. И это не идёт ни в какое сравнение с константным указателем. В этом месте вы можете доверять компилятору - неопределённого или неожиданного поведения не будет. Но я согласен, что было бы замечательно, если бы MinGW таки выдавал варнинг о таком формальном несоответствии параметров, даже если это и не влечёт за собой никаких серьёзных последствий. MSVC 2013, к примеру, пишет варнинг: `warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration`.

Comment: Про VS я знаю. Спасибо, в общем, я разобрался.